# Items disappear from queryset after update

Tags: django

Using Django 1.9, I have some code that makes two select queries on the same table in the same function. The code looks like this:

```
foo_ids = [1]  # A list of (actually uuids)
foo_qs = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=foo_ids, bar=False)
```

At this point, if I have print the queryset in the code, it would show at least one item:

```
print foo_qs  # [<Foo: Foo(id='1', ...)]
```

So I perform an `update()` on this queryset, modifying `bar`, but not `id`.

```
rows_updated = foo_qs.update(bar=True)  # 1 updated
```

At this point, `print foo_qs` will yield `[]`. Since `bar=False` is no longer met, this is expected. But if I now then create a new queryset under the code, such that the file looks similar to this:

```
foo_ids = [1]
foo_qs = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=foo_ids, bar=False)
rows_updated = foo_qs.update(bar=True)
new_foo_qs = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=foo_ids)  # Should contain 1 record
```

Despite records being in the database, `new_foo_qs` also contains nothing!

This can be resolved by first converting `foo_ids` to a set, like so.

```
foo_ids = [1]
foo_qs = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=foo_ids, bar=False)
rows_updated = foo_qs.update(bar=True)
foo_ids = set(foo_ids)
new_foo_qs = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=foo_ids)  # 1 record
```

Why is this happening? Is this some caching mechanism I need to know about?

Comment: I don't think that the example you have included reproduces your problem. If `foo_ids = [1]`, then `new_foo_qs` should give the same result whether or not you covert `foo_ids` to a set.

Comment: @Alasdair that's where this question came from, it's really, really weird that it works just by converting it to a set.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem starting with `foo_ids=[1]`. My `new_foo_qs` contains 1 record whether or not I convert to a set. There's something going on that you haven't included in your question.